# Storing multiple Address objects into a TreeSet from a Person class

Tags: java, object, treeset

Basically, what I am trying to do is store multiple addresses for each Person object. I have decided to achieve this by storing Address objects in a TreeSet of the Person class. Essentially I would like to store the toString() of each Address object I create into my TreeSet. I pass the properties of an Address object through the addAddress() method of the Person class, which passes the properties to the constructor of the Address class.

I receive an error on the specified line...

```
public class Person {
   private TreeSet<Address> addresses = new TreeSet<Address>();

   public void addAddress(String type, String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
     //ERROR ON THIS LINE BELOW
     Address addressObj = new Address(type, street, city, state, zip);
     addresses.add(addressObj);
   }
}

public class Address {
   private String type;
   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String zip;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return street + " " + city + " " + ", " + state + " " + zip + ": " + type;
   }

   public Address(String type, String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
       super();
       this.type = type;
       this.street = street;
       this.city = city;
       this.state = state;
       this.zip = zip;
   }
}


public class MainDriver {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Person p1 = new Person();
       p1.addAddress("Home", "321 Den Ave", "Orlando", "FL", "32792");
       p1.addAddress("Work", "4411 Alligator Court", "Orlando", "FL", "32792");
   }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Address cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
at Person.addAddress(Person.java:64)
at MainDriver.main(MainDriver.java:9)
```

To be clear: I do not want to store the address in one string because I want to be able to manipulate each property individually later on. I also do not want the Address Class properties to be stored in the Person Class as I need multiple iterations of the Address Class to be able to store multiple addresses for each Person object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, to put something into a TreeSet, they must be comparable. This is because a tree set will try to arrange your items in a tree structure. If it can't an exception will be thrown, so everything you put into a Tree set must implement `Comparable`.

However, addresses can't be logically compared, can they? It's really hard for you to write a `compareTo` method for addresses. How do you determine whether an address is "greater" than another?

Therefore, I think `TreeSet` is not a suitable data structure for this purpose. I suggest you use `HashSet` instead. Hash sets requires your items to implement `hashCode`, which is a method that returns a number that is unique to that object, and `equals`. If the objects' hash codes are equal, the two objects are also logically equal.

You can make use of `Objects.hash` to help you implement this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects,hash(type, street, city, state, zip);
}
```

Alternative, use one of the implementations generated by your IDE. Here's what my IntelliJ IDEA got:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = type.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + street.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + city.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + state.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + zip.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

The `equals` method should also be implemented too. You can do something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Address address = (Address) o;

    if (!type.equals(address.type)) return false;
    if (!street.equals(address.street)) return false;
    if (!city.equals(address.city)) return false;
    if (!state.equals(address.state)) return false;
    return zip.equals(address.zip);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, TreeSet requires that the elements be sorted. Either you have to construct the set and give it a Comparator that knows how to sort the objects you're adding or the objects themselves need to know how to compare to each other. You could have Address implement Comparable, but why are you using a TreeSet? Since your constructor is making the unnecessary (because it's implicit) call to super(), I guess you're new to Java? Maybe you don't need the sorting feature of TreeSet and you can get by with HashSet (if you just need uniqueness). Regardless, you should override hashcode() and equals() if you want the set to do what you expect. If you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IDEA then there is probably a code template to help out with that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are trying to do is you are storing an object in TreeSet.

Treeset is Sorted Collection, if you are storing the object in TreeSet the Object should implement Comparable and you should provide a condition on what basis object should be sorted.

Here is the Code :-

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Person {
    private Set<Address> addresses = new TreeSet<>();

    public void addAddress(String type, String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
        //ERROR ON THIS LINE BELOW
        Address addressObj = new Address(type, street, city, state, zip);
        addresses.add(addressObj);
    }
}

class Address implements Comparable{
    private String type;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return street + " " + city + " " + ", " + state + " " + zip + ": " + type;
    }

    public Address(String type, String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Address address = (Address)o;
        return this.type.compareTo(address.type);
    }
}


public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.addAddress("Home", "321 Den Ave", "Orlando", "FL", "32792");
        p1.addAddress("Work", "4411 Alligator Court", "Orlando", "FL", "32792");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
    }
}
```